# Multiple regex in function using php

Tags: php, regex, function

I wanted to pass data that contains `url` within it, and the `url` will be converted to click-able links, but the issue is that when i run the `function`, it reiterate 3 times and the data is treated 3 times. How can I have a single data output? I tried removing the concatenation `.=` to just `=` but then, only the last pattern is being treated. I want it in 3 pattern because I want to add `http` to the `href` when a user input is `www.ivotism.com`, it will be `<a href="http//www.ivotism.com">www.ivotism.com</a>` instead of `<a href="www.ivotism.com">www.ivotism.com</a>`.

```
function linkify($inputText) {
        //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
        $replacePattern1 = '/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i';
        $replacedText .=  preg_replace($replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $inputText);

        //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
        $replacePattern2 = '/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/i';
        $replacedText .=  preg_replace($replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', $inputText);

        //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
        $replacePattern3 = '/(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/i';
        $replacedText .=  preg_replace($replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>', $inputText);

        return $replacedText;
    }
```

I run the code as shown below:

```
$ab = "<br>1 http://www.ivotism.com <br>2 https://www.ivotism.com/hom.php?u=kira&id=2 <br>3 ftp://www.ivotism.com <br>4 w www.ivotism.com <br>5 info@ivotism.com"; echo 
linkify($ab);
```

This is the result I got:

1. 1 http://www.ivotism.com
2. 2 https://www.ivotism.com/hom.php?u=kira&id=2
3. 3 ftp://www.ivotism.com
4. 4 www.ivotism.com
5. 5 info@ivotism.com
6. 1 http://www.ivotism.com
7. 2 https://www.ivotism.com/hom.php?u=kira&id=2
8. 3 ftp://www.ivotism.com
9. 4 www.ivotism.com
10. 5 info@ivotism.com
11. 1 http://www.ivotism.com
12. 2 https://www.ivotism.com/hom.php?u=kira&id=2
13. 3 ftp://www.ivotism.com
14. 4 www.ivotism.com
15. 5 info@ivotism.com

Comment: You're using `$inputText` as the input each time. You need to use the result of the previous replacement.

Comment: You mean i should use `$replaceText` in pattern 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform all the replacements in a single call to `preg_replace`, by putting the regular expressions and replacements into arrays.

```
$resultText = preg_replace(array($replacePattern1, $replacePattern2, $replacePattern3),
                           array($replaceSub1, $replaceSub2, $replaceSub3),
                           $inputText);
```

Comment: Thats great, and there is no having problem with function redeclaration. its ok.